# How are tables managed in Lua? [Example of extrange behaviour]

Tags: lua, reference, insert, lua-table

I was trying to understand a Lua function to parse XML-formatted strings and I observed an unexpected behaviour on how tables were being handled. I summarised the problem as follows:

```
local stack = {}
local top = {}
table.insert(stack, top)

table.insert(top,{1,2,3})

top={'x','y','z'}

print(stack[1][1][1],stack[1][1][2],stack[1][1][3])
print(top[1],top[2],top[3])

>> 1 2 3
>> x y z
```

I don't get why the two outputs are not the same. If **top** is inserted into **stack** by reference, the first output would make sense if I didn't overwrite **top** with `top={'x','y','z'}`. Why isn't **stack** affected when I directly enter the values of **top**?

It looks as if `top={'x','y','z'}` created another sort of instance for **top**, in such a way that the values pointed by **stack** are being kept. Is this right? Lua documentation is scarce when you want to go into detail and I haven't found anything about this. It seems to me that this is a dangerous behaviour if it is not explicitly specified.

Regards

**_______Edit:_______**

I was making a mistake: `table.insert(top,{1,2,3})` is not the same as `top={'x','y','z'}`, it is the same as `top[1]={'x','y','z'}`.

So, reformulating the original question, we have the code:

```
local stack = {}
local top = {}
table.insert(stack, top)

table.insert(top,{1,2,3})

top[1]={4,5,6} -- it does change stack

top = {'x'}

print(stack[1][1][1],stack[1][1][2],stack[1][1][3])
print(top[1][1],top[1][2],top[1][3])

>>   4      5     6
>>  nil    nil   nil
```

Now, I see perfectly normal the second output, but I still have doubts predicting the first one.

If I replace `top = {'x'}` for `top[1] = 'x'` the output turns to

```
>> nil nil nil
>> nil nil nil
```

I have read the [Values and Types](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) section, but I still don't fully know what's wrong.
Sorry if I am making a silly mistake, but I can't see it.

Comment: `top={'x','y','z'}` _created another sort of instance for top, in such a way that the values pointed by stack are being kept. Is this right?_  - YES.  This is exactly what's going on. To make it more understandable, please note that your table does not have a name.  Only variables do.  So, `top` in RHS means "the value that is pointed to by variable "top" at the moment of execution of current line of a program"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question. I still wonder why in this case top behaves as it does

Comment: Please refrain from changing the very topic of your question when you realize your mistake. Your question was answered - leave it this way. Ask a new question regarding the new problem. This question is so all over the place I'm having trouble processing what it is you need

Comment: Well, my mistake did not explain the problem I had, It only explained why the two outputs weren't the same. The topic is the very same, that's why I did not ask a new question. I simply reformulated the question giving a **more specific** example of the behaviour I was asking for an explanation about.

Comment: Your question was why the output wasn't the same. It was answered.

Comment: My question was "Why isn't **stack** affected when I directly enter the values of **top**?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are values in Lua. Each table is a separate and distinct value. Variables are not names for values; they're just boxes that hold them for a time.

Multiple variables can refer to the same table. So after doing `top = {}`, the variable `top` has a reference to a table. By doing `table.insert(stack, top)`, now both `top` and `stack[1]` have a reference to the *same table*.

If you execute `top = {'x'}`, then you change what table is stored in `top`. You have put a new thing in that box. But `stack[1]` still refers to the table that was set into it.

It's not different from doing this:

```
var1 = 5;
var2 = var1;
var1 = 10;
```

`var2` is still *five*; it didn't become 10. `var2` has no connection to `var1`. It simply took the value that `var1` had *at that time*.

Where you're getting confused is in the difference between the table itself and its *contents*.

`top` contains a reference to a table. `top[1]` means to get the first element of the table referenced by `top`. If you assign something to `top[1]`, you are not modifying the variable; you are modifying the *contents* of the table referenced by that variable.

`top[1] = {4, 5, 6}` modifies what is stored in the table currently referenced by `top`. And at that time, that table is *also* being referenced by `stack[1]`. Therefore, you can access that table through `top` or through `stack`.

Once you change what table `top` references, by doing `top = {'x'}`, that is no longer true. `top` now references a different table. But the table it used to reference is still accessible via `stack`.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally got it. It is something like what I suggested about a new "instance" of top being created. More correctly, a new table is being associated with the variable top. That is what I was suspected, but what was confusing to me was knowing when the value was being modified or when the variable was being assigned to a new table. So, at the end of my question, when I suggest writting `top[1] = 'x'`I thought it would make point top[1] to a new value, but it is actually changin it. The tricky thing was identifying when a value is being modified or a new table is being referenced.

Comment: Assigning a value will **always** change what a variable/index is holding, and will **never** modify the value it had beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Lua operates on *values*, not on *variables*.

Try replacing

```
top={'x','y','z'}
```

by

```
top[2]='y'
```

Comment: Thanks, that made me realise that I was making a mistake thinking that table.insert(top,{1,2,3}) was the same as top={'x','y','z'}.

Comment: I have edited the question, because I still don't get what's going on.